# Get page title in webform

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a webform block on a page and i am looking for a way to get the webpage title in one of my fields. I have been looking for a while now and have not found a solution to my issue. One of the things that i found was using `[current-page:title]` but i cant get it to work i keep getting `[current-page:title]` to return in the field.

I found it off of this post: https://drupal.org/node/1782042, but i am afriad that i am using it the wrong way from what they explain and i may not understand what they are doing.

I have tried:

`[current-page:title]` and got `[current-page:title]` to return

`%get[current-page:title]` and got `%get[current-page:title]` to return

Does anyone know where i am going wrong or possibly have a solution to returning the title of the page in the webform field? I am pretty new to drupal development and any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

**---EDIT---**

The reason why `%title` is not an option is because it will only grab the title of the block. I need the current title of the page that the block is on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by upgrading to the webform 4.0 beta version. and used `[node:title]`.